# Format issue placing two views side by side in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-relativelayout

[image]

I have two views side by side inside a relative layout.  I want the format of both views to be like the one on the left ("Today's Special"). I've assigned both views the same attributes though they are different.

here is my xml.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:ignore="ExtraText">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/view_background"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/bg_row_background">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/delete_icon"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/ic_delete"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/ic_delete"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/padd_10"
        android:contentDescription="@string/deleteIcon"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_delete_white_24dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/padd_10"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@id/delete_icon"
        android:text="@string/delete"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="12sp" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/view_foreground"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:padding="@dimen/padd_5">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/ic_delete"
        android:background="@color/description"
        android:textColor="@color/item_name"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/namecat"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/ic_delete"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/name"
        android:background="@color/description"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/padd_10"
        android:textColor="@color/item_name"
        android:textSize="12sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried it using `ConstraintLayout`?

Comment: Highly recommend using ConstraintLyout

Comment: There is no text attribute in your last textview. Is that intentional or missing ?

Comment: Try to use [LinearLayout](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear) for linear UI like your view & consider using [RelativeLayout](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative) for hierarchial UI & also for Complex UI use [ContraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/).

Comment: In your xml there are 2 relative layouts. Which one contains the 2 views?

Comment: Try to Linear layout and Use Horizontal orientation in your parent View

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace FrameLayout with LinearLayout and weightsum property

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2"
    tools:ignore="ExtraText">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/view_background"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#978c8c">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/delete_icon"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_lock" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@id/delete_icon"
            android:text="@string/dummy_button"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="12sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/view_foreground"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/namecat"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/name"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textSize="12sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: this got me close to what I was looking for.